# Bot app not working from another User Role (Microsoft Bot Framework)

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, azure-bot-service

my bot is working on these situations : 
* Microsoft Framework @Test
* Bot emulator with Ngrok connected both locally and from Azure
* When I talk to it from main profile in Facebook  (which I set up the app)

**Its NOT working** when another user with a real fb profile, talk to it who I assigned him roles, either making him Test User of Developer User. It simply not answering anything when I send message to the page assigned!!

The error I receive (when posting from the other real profile) is

> "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError"

...from Microsoft Dev.Botframework page.

Azure also grab these errors in Graph.

I tested it either with making Public my App (from Facebook), but not luck

What I am missing ? can u help?

Comment: FIXED : seems that the error gone away when I typed /deleteprofile from the other Facebook Profile. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

FIXED : seems that the error gone away when I typed /deleteprofile from the other Facebook Profile. Now its working –